# Обработка нажатия мышью на символ С++

Tags: c++, консоль

Возможно ли обработать момент когда пользователь клацнул на символ (например-квадратик) в консоли?

Comment: Возможно. Если под windows, то см. функции ReadConsoleInput(), PeekConsoleInput(). https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput

Comment: Конечно же возможно